# Анимация, плавное увеличение и уменьшение изображения Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, анимация, pygame

Столкнулся с проблемой, пишу простенький кликер, и мне нужно чтобы при клике изображение моба сначала плавно увеличивалось, а затем плавно уменьшалось при достижении определенных размеров.

Пробовал сделать сам, но либо `pygame.transform.scale()`, не работало.
Либо я что-то делал не так.

Чат Гпт тоже проблему решить не может. Код который он предоставляет оставил ниже. 
Буду признателен если поможете правильно реализовать этот фрагмент кода.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

# Инициализация Pygame
pygame.init()

# Определение размеров окна
width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Увеличение и уменьшение картинки")

# Загрузка изображения
image = pygame.image.load("image.jpg")
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (100, 100))  # Изменение размера изображения
image_rect = image.get_rect()

# Исходные размеры изображения
original_width, original_height = image_rect.width, image_rect.height

# Параметры для анимации
scale_factor = 1.25  # Множитель для изменения размера
scaling = False     # Флаг для отслеживания анимации

# Функция для плавного изменения размера изображения
def animate_scale(target_width, target_height):
    global image, image_rect, scaling

    # Определение шагов изменения размера
    step_width = (target_width - image_rect.width) / 20
    step_height = (target_height - image_rect.height) / 20

    # Изменение размера путем плавного увеличения/уменьшения
    for _ in range(20):
        image_rect.width += step_width
        image_rect.height += step_height
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(image_rect.width), int(image_rect.height))), image_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

    # Завершение анимации
    scaling = False

# Основной цикл игры
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            # Проверка, не выполняется ли уже анимация
            if not scaling:
                if image_rect.width == original_width and image_rect.height == original_height:
                    # Увеличение картинки
                    animate_scale(int(original_width * scale_factor), int(original_height * scale_factor))
                elif image_rect.width == int(original_width * scale_factor) and image_rect.height == int(original_height * scale_factor):
                    # Уменьшение картинки
                    animate_scale(original_width, original_height)
                scaling = True

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(image_rect.width), int(image_rect.height))), image_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)
```

Comment: А в чём ошибка то? Он не работает, или работает, но некорректно? предоставьте больше информации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратите внимание, что я изменил некоторые размеры и установил свое изображение.
Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Увеличение и уменьшение картинки")

# Загрузка изображения     vvvvvvvv    <------------------ установите свое -------
image = pygame.image.load("lena.jpg")
image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (200, 200))  # размера изоб-я был (100, 100)
image_rect = image.get_rect()

# Исходные размеры изображения
original_width, original_height = image_rect.width, image_rect.height

# Параметры для анимации
scale_factor = 2.0                       # Множитель для изменения размера было 1.25
scaling = False                          # Флаг для отслеживания анимации

# Функция для плавного изменения размера изображения
def animate_scale(target_width, target_height):
    global image, image_rect, scaling

# Шаг изменения размера
# --------------> vv <--------------- Определите самостоятельно ---------------
    step_width =  10                 # (target_width - image_rect.width) / 20
    step_height = 10                 # (target_height - image_rect.height) / 20

    # Изменение размера путем плавного увеличения/уменьшения
    for _ in range(20)  
# !!! + vvvvvvvvvvvvvv                                       <------------------
        if not scaling:                                    # <------------------
            image_rect.width += step_width
            image_rect.height += step_height
        else:                                              # <------------------
# !!! + ^^^^                 vv         
            image_rect.width -= step_width                 # <------------------
            image_rect.height -= step_height               # <------------------
            
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(image, 
            (int(image_rect.width), int(image_rect.height))), image_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

    # Завершение анимации
# ???    scaling = False                                   # ??? <---------------

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
         
            if not scaling:
                if image_rect.width == original_width and \
                    image_rect.height == original_height:
                    # Увеличение картинки
                    animate_scale(int(original_width * scale_factor), 
                                  int(original_height * scale_factor))
#                elif image_rect.width == int(original_width * scale_factor) and image_rect.height == int(original_height * scale_factor):
#                    # Уменьшение картинки
#                    animate_scale(original_width, original_height)
#                scaling = True
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                 
            else: 
                animate_scale(image_rect.width, image_rect.height)
            scaling = not scaling
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(image_rect.width), int(image_rect.height))), image_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**lena.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Валерчик что не так?

Comment: Все верно, спасибо, но не могли бы вы подсказать, как можно увеличивать его без потери качества? Просто мое изображение сильно искажается при увеличении

Comment: @Валерчик пожалуйста. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос и приложите все необходимое для демонстрации проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, это общий подход во всех `GUI` фреймворках на любых языках программирования: **нельзя делать логику с циклами внутри обработки события**.

Ваш обработчик событий может менять состояние, переключать какие-то флаги, но потом должен быть максимально быстрый выход из обработчика событий, чтобы отдать контроль фреймворку. Потому что вся отрисовка экрана происходит тоже через **обработку событий самим фреймворком**. Пока вы сидите внутри обработчика событий и рисуете там что-то в цикле, **на экране ничего отрисовываться не будет**.

Так что при обработке событий меняйте состояние, переходите на очередной шаг увеличения/уменьшения, но всю отрисовку (зависящую от текущего состояния, установленного обрабатываемыми вами событиями) производите уже **после выхода из обработчика событий**.